# How can I make an object to face the direction it's moving like the birds at angry birds 2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity2D. I want to make my object face to the direction it's moving.
When the object moves to left it will face left direction.
When the object moves to up it will face up direction.

I want it to be like the birds at angry birds 2 when they're flying.

Comment: What have you tried?  We need to see your code if you want us to help fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a 2D expert but you could do something like this

```
private Vector3 lastFramePos;

private void Update()
{
    // get the direction
    var direction = (transfor.position - lastFramePos).normalized;

    // set the look direction depending on your needs e.g.
    transform.right = direction;

    // don't forget to update the lastFramePos
    lastFramePos = transform.position;
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*